# jQuery, qTip: tooltips font-size: always the same

Tags: jquery-plugins, qtip

I'm using qTip jquery-plugin for my tooltips.

I cannot change the font-size of the tooltips. This is the code.. any number 2..4..8 produces the same results.

```
$('.option img[title]').qtip({  
    style: { name: 'light', border: {width: 0}, title: { 'font-size': 2 } },        
        position: {
            corner: {
                target: 'topMiddle',
                tooltip: 'bottomMiddle'
                }
        }             
    });
```

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved with CSS:

```
.qtip-content {
    font-size:12px;
}
```

Comment: line-height: 14px; // (2px more than font-size may also help make the text look better as the font size increases)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the "**px**" and you can add any `css property` to your tool tip but you have to put it in quotation marks.

so try this (it worked for me)

```
'font-size' : '12px'
```

Answer (score -2):

Try removing the quotes around font-size

```
style: { name: 'light', border: {width: 0}, title: { font-size: 2 } }
```

Comment: Quoting properties like that is specifically mentioned in the docs.